# Formatear registros de un ArraList<String>

Tags: java, netbeans, arraylist, class, jtextfield

En una clase tengo el siguiente método:

```
public static ArrayList<String> recuperarTodosVehiculos(){
    ArrayList<String> listaVehiculos = new ArrayList<String>();
    

    try{
        
        Statement s = ConnectionDB.conn.createStatement();
        
        ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT mat_veh, marca_veh, kms_veh, precio_veh, nombre_prop from Vehículos, "
                                        + "propietarios WHERE propietarios.id_prop = vehículos.id_prop");
        while(rs.next()){
            listaVehiculos.add("\n" + 
                                    "Matrícula: " + rs.getString("mat_veh") + "\n" + 
                                    "Marca: " + rs.getString("marca_veh") + "\n" +
                                    "KMs: " + rs.getString("kms_veh") + "\n" +
                                    "Precio: " + rs.getString("precio_veh") + "\n" +
                                    "Propietario: " + rs.getString("nombre_prop") + "\n" +
                                    "----------------------------------------------\n");
        }

    } catch(SQLException e){
        listaVehiculos = null;
        System.out.println("Error en la consulta de recuperar todos los vehículos.");
    }
    
    return listaVehiculos;
}
```

cada registro del ArrayList listaVehiculos lo he formateado de esa manera.

Cuando en otra clase llamo a ese método, me muestra cada registro del ArrayList como una línea String pero sin saltos de línea. Todo en una misma línea, y yo quiero que se vea el mismo formato que como se almacenó o si hay alguna forma de formatear la salida del método.

```
private void bRecTodosVehiculosActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                   
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, VehiculosDAO.recuperarTodosVehiculos(), "TODOS LOS VEHÍCULOS", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    MostrarDatos datosFrame = new MostrarDatos();
    datosFrame.setVisible(true);
    datosFrame.tfMostrarDatos.setText(VehiculosDAO.recuperarTodosVehiculos().get(0));
}
```

Pues eso, ¿cómo podría formatear la salida de la llamada a ese método?

Comment: No entiendo tu problema. ¿Te refieres a que los saltos entre los valores: `Matricula`, `Marca`, etc  de **un mismo registro** no se muestran o a que no hay saltos **entre los diferentes registros**?

Comment: No se muestran los saltos entre los valores Matrícula, Marca... eso es. Entre los diferentes registros si porque hay me está mostrando el valor 0, pero en una línea.

Comment: Considera que `\n` **no representa un salto de línea para todas las plataformas**, por tanto, y para permanecer conforme al espíritu de Java, que es multiplataforma, prueba a cambiar todos tus `\n` por esto: `System.getProperty("line.separator")` o por esto si usas Java 7+: `System.lineSeparator()`, el cual agregará el salto de línea propio de la plataforma en que se ejecute el programa. Por cierto, es mejor usar un `StringBuilder` para concatenar cadenas.

Comment: Cambiando \n por System.getProperty("line.separator") tengo el mismo problema. Sin embargo, si llamo a esa función en un joptionpane si que funcionan los saltos de linea, tanto utilizando \n como la forma que tú me has dicho.

Comment: O, `String.format` puede ser útil para este caso. Prueba algo así: `listaVehiculos.add(String.format("%nMatrícula: %s%nMarca: %s%nKMs: %s%nPrecio: %s%nPropietario: %s%n----------------------------------------------%n", rs.getString("mat_veh"),rs.getString("marca_veh"),rs.getString("kms_veh"),rs.getString("precio_veh"),rs.getString("nombre_prop"));` [Según la doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html), el marcador `%n` te crea un salto de línea conforme a la plataforma que estés usando.

Comment: Y, ¿qué tipo de objeto es `datosFrame` exactamente? ¿Ese objeto admite datos formateados y/o saltos de línea? ¿Ese objeto tiene alguna configuración que reemplaza o evita los saltos de línea?

Comment: datosFrame es un objeto creado a partir de la clase MostrarDatos la cual contiene un TextField en donde pondré el texto del registro del arraylist. Lo que pasa que me sale en una línea continua.

Comment: Ya, eso quería saber. Los `JTextField` no admiten saltos de línea. Si quieres saltos de línea debes usar un elemento de tipo  `JTextArea`. [La doc es bastante clara al respecto](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html): *If you need to obtain more than one line of input from the user, use a [text area](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html)*. Por tanto, el elemento al que apliques el texto, debe ser un `JTextArea`, no un `JTextField`.

Comment: @A.Cedano Vale, ese era el problema. Muchas gracias. El JTextArea si que admite saltos de línea. No lo sabía.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En primer lugar, Java es un lenguaje **multiplataforma**, por tanto, adapta tu código, para que sea coherente con el espíritu de Java. `\n` no respresenta un [salto de línea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) en todas las plataformas, por tanto, evita su uso, cambiándolo por una de las opciones que te ofrece Java para asegurar la compatibilidad entre plataformas:

- El marcador `%n` si usas [`String.format()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html) o
- El método [`System.lineSeparator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator()) (desde Java 7) o
- El método [`System.getProperty("line.separator")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty(java.lang.String)) (antes de Java 7).

Por otra parte, los `JTextField` **no admiten saltos de línea**, [la doc es clara en ese punto](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html), dice que para múltiples líneas debes usar `JTextArea`:

> If you need to obtain more than one line of input from the user, use a
> [text area](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html).

---

> Si necesita obtener más de una línea de entrada del usuario, use un
> área de texto.

Por tanto, poniendo el código así:

```
listaVehiculos.add(String.format("%nMatrícula: %s%nMarca: %s%nKMs: %s%nPrecio: %s%nPropietario: %s%n----------------------------------------------%n",
    rs.getString("mat_veh"),
    rs.getString("marca_veh"),
    rs.getString("kms_veh"),
    rs.getString("precio_veh"),
    rs.getString("nombre_prop"));
```

Y aplicando ese contenido a un `JTextArea`, debería funcionar, y tu código quedaría independiente de la plataforma en que sea ejecutado.